# SQL: How to return an non-existing row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following table:

```
=================================================
| color_id | parent_id | language_id | name     |
=================================================
| 1        | 50        | 1           | Black    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Then say I need the row `WHERE parent_id = 50 AND language_id = 2`. Obviously, I would get nothing back based on my example table. However, I still need a result -- probably something like this:

```
=================================================
| color_id | parent_id | language_id | name     |
=================================================
| NULL     | 50        | 2           | NULL     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do this?  It's an interesting question, but I'm hard pressed to think of a reason for it.

Comment: @David: To handle a default value...

Comment: @David: OMG Ponies is right. I'm trying to use COALESCE to do language translations (say, if `name` exist for a particular language, then use it; otherwise use the first non-NULL `name` that exist). Problem is when the row for a particular language does not exist, then I can't seem to use COALESCE. If I get a row with the NULL values, then I can use my COALESCE solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do a union query of both the potentially valid record and your default, then select the first one:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT color_id, parent_id, language_id, name, 1 as order_rank
 FROM some_table
 WHERE parent_id = %parent_id% AND language_id = %language_id%
 UNION
 SELECT NULL, %parent_id%, %language_id%, NULL, 2 as order_rank
)
ORDER BY order_rank
LIMIT 1
```

(Edited with static value for ordering as suggested by OMG Ponies)

Comment: I'm certain there's something with either IF or CASE, but MySQL syntax isn't the flavour I'm normally used to.

Comment: +1:  Only thing I'd add would be a statically defined value for ordering by, to ensure the proper row is returned when the value searched for exists.

Comment: Agreed, a very nice solution.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, can you please elaborate on what you mean by adding "a statically defined value for ordering by"? Thanks!

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: I believe he meant it as I put up in the latest edit. It enforces ranking, that's for sure.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: ^ what he said

Comment: I kinda have to question the general approach, though. Could you instead have a cover function for this query and check the number of rows returned? On 0, you could output your default value constructed in the same way as your default record above.

Answer (score 0):

try working with LEFT JOIN statement. i'm probably not doing this 100% but a bit of trial and error on your part should make this work.

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field3, table2.field4
FROM my_table table1 
LEFT JOIN my_table table2 ON table1.field1=table2.field1 OR table1.field2=table2.field2
```

Answer (score 0):

a left join on a forced fixed value first table SHOULD work.

```
select 
      YourTable.color_id,
      ForcedSQL1Record.parent_id,
      ForcedSQL1Record.language_id,
      YourTable.name
   from 
      ( select 50 as Parent_ID,
                2 as Language_ID
            from YourTable
            limit 1 ) ForcedSQL1Record
      left join
         YourTable
            on ForcedSQL1Record.Parent_ID = YourTable.Parent_ID
            AND ForcedSQL1Record Language_ID = YourTable.Language_ID
```